# Google Maps: How to remove a marker after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I add markers on Google Map using the following code

```
function addDynamicMarker(location) {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }));
  iterator++;
}
```

I have constant stream of data coming in from server and I add it to Map by calling

```
  connection.onmessage = function(e) {
    var parse = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var coordinates = parse["geo"]["coordinates"];
    console.log("coordinates:" + JSON.stringify(coordinates, undefined, 2));
    addDynamicMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]));
  };
```

**Problem?**
- This keeps on creating new points on the map and becomes takes over all of the place
- Since new `google.maps.LatLng` are getting created, they end up taking a lot of memory

**What I need?**
I need a way to that when the marker is pushed, that market is deleted after `2 seconds`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use setTimeout to schedule the marker for removal after 2 seconds.

Comment: [proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxrtR/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout to schedule the removal of the marker:

```
function addDynamicMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        // icon: image,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        marker.setMap(null);
        delete marker;
    }, 2000);
    return marker;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxrtR/)